# Struggling with simple reverse function

Tags: python, list

I want to reverse the middle of a list:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

[1,2,3,7,6,5,4,8,9,10]
```

As you can see, three elements [1,2,3] aren't reversed at the beginning, and neither are three elements at the end [8,9,10].

But I just cannot think how to do it with "elegance." I tried a lot of combinations such as:

```
ls2 = ls[:4] + ls[::-1] + ls[:-4]
```

but I'm getting duplicates. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the list of arbitrary length l assuming that we want to keep head and tail of 
int(l/3) and reverse the middle.

```
l = len(s); n = int(l/3)
ls[:n] + ls[-n-1:n-1:-1] + ls[-n:]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ls= ls[:3]+ls[3:7][::-1]+ls[7:]
```

---

```
ls =ls[:3]+ls[-4:2:-1]+ls[-3:]
```

---

- `ls[::-1]` will reverse the whole list, you need to set the start point and endpoint.

Comment: `ls[3:7][::-1]` seems like overkill. Why not `ls[6:2:-1]`?

Comment: By the way, this is not an in-place modification of the existing object, but rather a reassignment of the name. `ls[3:-3] = ls[-4:2:-1]` is shorter to read, creates only one temp list (instead of 3), and modifies the existing object in-place.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply assign the desired slice in reverse to the target slice:

```
ls[3:7] = ls[6:2:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls2=ls[::-1]
ls2[:4]=ls[:4]
ls2[:-4]=ls[:-4]
```